# Add a GeoTIFF layer to layer group via REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

The layer and layer group are present in the GeoServer. I send a PUT request to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{myworkspace}/layergroups/{mylayerGroup}.json` with my json which is an updated version of what I receive through a GET to the same endpoint, with an updated `publishables` node:

```
...
"publishables": {
   "published": [
      {
         "@type": "layer",
         "name": "cite:wp7504124-art-laptop-wallpapers_modified",
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/layers/wp7504124-art-laptop-wallpapers_modified.json"
      }
   ]
},
...
```

And it all seems well up to this point since I get a `200:OK` response. However, when I look on GeoServer the layer is not added.

The logs when GeoServer receives the first request after it's started are different from the next times. The first time I get thousands of lines like these:

```
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 TRACE [org.geotools.filter] - kid 0 [#text: 1]
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - processing 1
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - processing root Function
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - attribute name with value of StringTransform
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - processing root PropertyName
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - processing root Literal
2023-02-25 12:34:05,259 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - processing literal [ogc:Literal: null]
2023-02-25 12:34:05,260 TRACE [org.geotools.filter] - literal elements (1) [ogc:Literal: null]
```

followed by:

```
25 Feb 12:34:05 DEBUG [org.geotools.xml.styling] - setting anchorPoint org.geotools.styling.AnchorPointImpl@40b435b
25 Feb 12:34:05 DEBUG [org.geotools.xml.styling] - setting displacement null
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 INFO [org.geotools.util.factory] - Factory implementations for category CoordinateOperationFactory:
  org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.operation.AuthorityBackedFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.operation.BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 DEBUG [org.geotools.referencing.factory] - The EPSG factory org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.hsql.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory will not timeout
25 Feb 12:34:05 INFO [org.geotools.util.factory] - Factory implementations for category CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory:
  org.vfny.geoserver.crs.GeoserverWKTOperationFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CoordinateOperationFactoryUsingWKT
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.URN_AuthorityFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.HTTP_AuthorityFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.HTTP_URI_AuthorityFactory
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstEpsgDecorator
  org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.hsql.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory
25 Feb 12:34:05 INFO [org.geotools.referencing.factory] - user_projections/epsg_operations.properties was not found, using the default set of coordinate operation overrides (normally empty)
25 Feb 12:34:05 INFO [org.geotools.referencing.factory] - Using "file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.20.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.20.3.jar!/org/vfny/geoserver/crs/epsg_operations.properties" as EPSG factory.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - THROW  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): could not find implementation.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - THROW  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): could not find implementation.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (ReferencingFactoryContainer)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (ReferencingFactoryContainer): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
25 Feb 12:34:05 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (CoordinateOperationFactory, COORDINATE_OPERATION_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
```

But the second time onward the only log will be this:

```
25 Feb 12:37:36 INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - PUT layer group Iran_night, workspace cite
```

with no change in the result.

More info:
The layer is a GeoTIFF I uploaded through the importer extension, following the guide in [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html#uploading-and-optimizing-a-geotiff-with-ground-control-points), however I didn't do the optimizations (`gdalwarp`, `translate`, `addo`). But I doubt that's the issue since **adding the layer through GeoServer interface just works**.

### Update: With XML

Just appending a node to the XML I receive from the server I get a `500:Server Error` with these logs:

```
26 Feb 14:13:20 INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - PUT layer group Iran_night, workspace cite
26 Feb 14:13:20 ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] -
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.checkLayerGroupResourceIsInWorkspace(CatalogImpl.java:1098)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.checkLayerGroupResourceIsInWorkspace(CatalogImpl.java:1070)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.validate(CatalogImpl.java:1014)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.save(CatalogImpl.java:1126)
        at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.save(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1499)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AdvertisedCatalog.save(AdvertisedCatalog.java:336)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractCatalogDecorator.save(AbstractCatalogDecorator.java:520)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.save(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:417)
        at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.LayerGroupController.layerGroupPut(LayerGroupController.java:213)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
26 Feb 14:13:20 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - Failure in @ExceptionHandler public void org.geoserver.rest.RestControllerAdvice.handleGeneralException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.io.OutputStream) throws java.lang.Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No input String specified
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
        at 
...
```

The XML I send is:

```
<layerGroup>
    <name>Iran_night</name>
    <mode>SINGLE</mode>
    <title>Iran (Dark)</title>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <advertised>true</advertised>
    <workspace>
        <name>cite</name>
    </workspace>
    <publishables>
        <published
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="layer">
            <name>cite:wp7504124-art-laptop-wallpapers_modified</name>
            <atom:link
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/layers/wp7504124-art-laptop-wallpapers_modified.xml" type="application/xml"/>
        </published>
    </publishables>
    <styles>
        <style>
            <name>cite:google-night</name>
            <atom:link
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/styles/google-night.xml" type="application/xml" />
        </style>
    </styles>
    <bounds>
        <minx>4903870.698713262</minx>
        <maxx>7051031.093396437</maxx>
        <miny>2815130.0325668734</miny>
        <maxy>4835666.54540779</maxy>
        <crs class="projected">EPSG:3857</crs>
    </bounds>
    <metadata>
        <entry key="cachingEnabled">false</entry>
    </metadata>
    <attribution>
        <logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
        <logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
    </attribution>
    <dateCreated>2022-06-09 16:54:06.402 UTC</dateCreated>
    <dateModified>2023-02-25 09:07:36.684 UTC</dateModified>
</layerGroup>
```

Comment: does it work if you use XML?

Comment: @IanTurton Please see my update.

Comment: the XML error seems to think you are sending it a `Layer` when you've actually sent a `LayerGroup` - so your endpoint URL might be wrong?

Comment: Yes, should've double-checked that. I updated the logs.